# $\liminf$ for non-negative sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ $b_n$ be two non-negative sequence. I know that 
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\geq \liminf a_n+\liminf b_n
$$
(In my case I do have $a_n$ and $b_n$ bounded). However, I somehow rememberd that if both of sequences are non-negative, we have 
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)= \liminf a_n+\liminf b_n
$$
Is this true?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Sorry I might confused you. I don't know whether the limit exists or not. I only know the $\liminf$ exists since both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are bounded and non-negative.

Comment: Yes, I figured you meant that after you edited. I already deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
\begin{equation}
a_n=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if } n\text{ is even}\\
1&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and let $b_n=1-a_n$. Then $\lim\inf(a_n+b_n)=\lim\inf(a_n+(1-a_n))=1$, but $\lim\inf a_n=\lim\inf b_n=0$. Thus,

$$1=\lim\inf(a_n+b_n)\neq\lim\inf a_n+\lim\inf b_n=0+0=0$$

but, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both nonnegative and bounded. This provides you with a counterexample, your statement is false.